# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth working different on iOS 14 vz 15

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uifont

Context:

Im observing a bigger down size of my text when using `.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` on iOS15 vz iOS14 Xcode 13 but i haven't find any release notes explaining why.

[image]

My observations are this: Same frame for the label result on a different text size in a proportion of heiht: 1, width:4

even more stranger if I increase the height of the frame the behavior returns to be like the old one and this don't affect behavior  on iOS14

```
// First label is render smaller on iOS 15 vz 14
UILabel *yourLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 160, 40)];
[yourLabel1 setTextColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
[yourLabel1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor systemRedColor]];
[yourLabel1 setFont:[UIFont  boldSystemFontOfSize:52]];
[yourLabel1 setText:@"HELLO"];

yourLabel1.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2;
yourLabel1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[self.view addSubview:yourLabel1];

// Second label is render equal on iOS 15 and 14 only difference is a change on the height 
UILabel *yourLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 160, 60)];
[yourLabel2 setTextColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
[yourLabel2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor systemRedColor]];
[yourLabel2 setFont:[UIFont  boldSystemFontOfSize:52]];
[yourLabel2 setText:@"HELLO"];
yourLabel2.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2;
yourLabel2.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

 
[self.view addSubview:yourLabel2];
```

why I really wanna now is why is this happening, did something change on iOS15?

Comment: @Cristik is also on real devices